# IEEE floating point representation

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

I have created following program to find the bit pattern of floating point no. but i got different then i calculated:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    float f = 1.234;
    char *ch;
    ch = (char *)(&f);
    printf("\n%d\n", *ch);
    ch++;
    printf("\n%d\n", *ch);
    ch++;
    printf("\n%d\n", *ch);
    ch++;
    printf("\n%d\n", *ch);

//  printf("%d %d %d %d", *ch, *(ch+1), *(ch+2), *(ch+3));
    printf("\n%f %e", f, f);
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me output:

```
-74

-13

-99

63

1.234000 1.234000e+00
```

What does it mean because i was expecting bit pattern as:

`00111111 10111011 11100111 0110110`

where i am wrong please correct me

Comment: Why were you expecting that bit pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got that bit pattern from.

For IEEE-754, `1.234` is equivalent to an underlying representation of `0x3F9DF3B6` (see e.g. http://babbage.cs.qc.edu/IEEE-754/Decimal.html).  So we have:

```
0x3F = 00111111 =  63
0x9D = 10011101 = -99 (as a signed char)
0xF3 = 11110011 = -13
0xB6 = 10110110 = -74
```

Depending on your system endianness, you might find that these bytes come up in the other order.

Answer (score 1):

There is no binary `printf` format built into standard C.  You'll need to write your own if that's the output format you want.  You could get closer by using `%x` to see hexadecimal output; maybe that will get you what you need?

Comment: OP also needs to use `unsigned char` rather than `char`.

Answer (score 0):

The bit pattern that you expect is wrong, it should be:

```
{"00111111", "10011101", "11110011", "10110110"} = {63, -99, -13, -74}
```

which produces exactly the numbers you got.

The sign, exponent and significant are:
    0, 127, 1962934